# ::after на который будет влиять display: flex;

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая шапка. Можно ли сделать с помощью ::after разделитель который будет учитываться в display: flex;. Чтоб не создавать пустой div для разделителя

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    background-color: #ff2970;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 40px 15px;
}

.header__items {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__item--separate::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="q.css">
        <title>Header</title>
    </head>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__items">
            <div class="header__item">
                LOGO
            </div>
            <div class="header__item header__item--separate">
                <a href="">Ссылка</a>
                <a href="">Ссылка</a>
                <a href="">Ссылка</a>
            </div>
            <div class="header__item">
                что-то еще
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно, псевдоэлементы `::before` и `::after` учитываются как элементы во Flexbox. Но стоит учитывать тот момент, что данные псевдоэлементы создаются внутри того блока, к которому они добавляются, если они должны быть в потоке с элементами, тогда придётся использовать что-то другое

Comment: ммм. Спасибо, не знал